# Undead Windows 7 service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, windows-services

I created a Windows 7 service in Visual Studio 2010. Test install crashed and left lots of debris: service shows in the list of services but will not start (`Referenced file does not exist`), is impossible to uninstall (`Action valid only for services that are installed`) and is not shown in the Programs and Features applet.

Is there a list of installed services that I could hack?

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

https://serverfault.com/questions/2514/how-can-i-remove-uninstall-an-orphaned-service

You can determine the service name by first bringing up the list of services by going to the Start menu --> Run... and then typing "services.msc" and pressing enter. You should see your service in the list.  Then right-click it and see what it says for "service name" (usually an abbreviation).

Good luck.